# Game shifts to edge of screen when clicking Play button in Unity

Tags: unity

I’m attempting to help my young daughter who is trying to learn Unity. I know very little about the program.

Recently, she developed a basic game consisting of a dragon and a person.

When she presses the play button, the game shifts to the edge of the screen and does not start.

I have attempted to research the issue but with my limited knowledge on the subject I could not find anything. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

09/22 - After reading the comment and following the recommendations  I do believe it’s a camera issue. I’ve attempted to move the camera around using the X, Y and Z axis is but I can’t get it to actually change the view. See the attached screenshot.
[image]

10/02/2020 - My daughter went back and redid the game from the start. The issue is that the game will not allow her to enter play mode until she places the dragon. However, as soon as she places the dragon and presses play the game moves the camera. So the issue apparently occurs prior to or at the time she places the dragon but because she can't enter play mode prior to this point I'm not sure where the issue occurs.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of what you see after pressing the play button? This may help us understand what's happening. Also, if you can ensure the Console tab is displayed (find it under the Window menu --> General --> Console), that can show us if the editor is reporting any errors that might affect the game.

Comment: From your update, there are two major possibilities: 1) you have two Cameras in your scene, so the one you're trying to move doesn't affect the position of the one that's doing the rendering. 2) you have a component that's trying to control the position of the camera, so even when you move the camera, this script puts it back where it was. We can't see enough of your setup to be able to tell you which of these cases you're dealing with though, or what you need to do to fix it. Are you able to reproduce the problem in a new, empty scene? Let us know each step we need to follow to replicate it.

Comment: It would also help to see your Console tab, so we can verify there are no errors that might be preventing the game from playing as expected.

Comment: I'm not sure on the exact problem given the current documentation, but typically you cannot enter playmode if you have an error (normally script related). You might also want to be testing your game using FullHD (1920x1080) resolution rather than "Free Aspect".  This normally makes things easier since your camera view in "Free Aspect" will change depending on how big your Game tab is.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the Window menu and choosing Layouts --> Default. That should change your window to look something like this:

[image: Default Window Layout]

(You can also try the other standard layouts to see if any of them behave better for you)

Click the Game tab indicated by the red arrow in the screengrab above, then click the Maximize on Play button:

[image: Maximize on Play Button]

With this enabled, clicking the Play button should make the game expand to fill your whole Editor window.

If it's still not behaving correctly for you, editing your question to include a screenshot of what you're seeing may give us some clues for what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the camera,

[image: Layout]

In Unity, the Camera is the viewpoint through which the player is able to view your game. The problem might be that your camera is not set up correctly. There are two ways to do this:

1. In the screenshot above, I have selected the Main Camera in the hierarchy, it is highlighted in blue. In the Scene View, you can see the small pop-up in the bottom-right corner, this shows what the player can view on running the game. Going back to the scene view, there is a white rectangle with some handles (squares) on its side. This represents what the camera can see. You can move this around or adjust its size, try to adjust, and resize it so the camera popup in the bottom-right shows what you want the player to see.
2. My preferred way to this is to drag the Game Tab from next to the scene tab (above the scene view) and bring it to the bottom. If you do this, you will see that the lower tabs show what the camera can see, while the upper tab shows. the scene view. Keep adjusting the camera as stated in (1) until the girl and dragon are visible in the Game View (lower tab).

If this doesn't work, then edit your question to include a screenshot (and some more details). That might help us figure out what exactly the problem is.